# Show that $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i\neq j} \sin\left(X_i X_j\right)$ converges almost surely to a constant

Tags: probability, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables. How does one show that

$$ \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i\neq j}^n \sin\left(X_i X_j\right) $$ converges almost surely to a constant?

Comment: Is this a homework question or something from a textbook? Could you add information about the nature of the question such that the answers can be adapted for this.

Comment: If it is a homework, then you should add _self-study_ tag and maybe include your attempts or ideas in the post so that answers can be built upon your current progress.

Comment: Do you need to proof convergence in probability to a constant or convergence almost sure to a constant?

Comment: This is a problem I found on a statistics entrance exam for the Indian Statistical Institute (if I remember correctly); I’ve not yet found it any textbook although if you know of (similar) problems in a textbook I’d be happy to hear a reference. My main issue is that I don’t know of an LLN that finds purchase with this kind of dependence structure.

Comment: Please post your result for weak LLN. That should be good enough for now.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty can you edit your question according to the first two comments.

Comment: There are no distributional assumptions on $X_i$, presumably because slapping the $\sin$ on there makes them bounded (and hence $L^p$ ). My guess is that some form of martingale convergence theorem is involved here.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty Yes, boundedness is definitely key here. I updated my answer but am pretty sure there is an easier solution.

Comment: What you have is a U-statistic $\frac1{\binom{n}{2}}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\sin(X_iX_j)$. Reading up on SLLN/consistency for U-statistics could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is worth elaborating @StubbornAtom's sharp comment as applying the U-statistics theory is perhaps the most direct way to prove this proposition.   To this end, identify the random variable of interest as the U-statistic
\begin{align}
U_n := U(X_1, \ldots, X_n) := \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}h(X_i, X_j),
\end{align}
where $h(x, y) = \sin(xy)$ is the "kernel" function of this U-statistic. Now the result immediately follows by the following theorem (cf. *Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics* by R.Serfling, Theorem 5.4.A) because $|h| \leq 1$:

> *If $E[|h|] < \infty$, then $U_n$ converges to $\theta = E[h(X_1, X_2)]$ almost surely.*

For more details (e.g., which references provided the proof to this theorem), refer to the same reference, Section 5.4.  At high-level, the key of the proof is the [Hoeffding representation](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hoeffding_decomposition) of the quantity $U_n - \theta$.

Comment: Hmm this does seem to be a martingale approach in disguise... this is probably the method the examiners expected, although they probably expected students to use the reverse martingale convergence theorem directly rather than the theorem on U-statistics (which isn't part of the standard undergraduate curriculum).

Answer (score 7):

#### In the case of the weak LLN

We can prove that the variance of the sum decreases for increasing $n$ (then applying Chebyshev's inequality).

For simplicity of writing  the equations, I will define $$Z_{\mathscr{ij}} = \sin(X_\mathscr{i}X_\mathscr{j})$$ and $$S_n = \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{\mathscr{i}\neq \mathscr{j}} Z_{\mathscr{ij}}$$

The variance of the sum can be computed as

$$\operatorname{Var}(S_n) =  \left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \right)^2 \sum_{\mathscr{i}\neq \mathscr{j}} \sum_{\mathscr{k}\neq\mathscr{l}} \operatorname{Cov}(Z_{\mathscr{ij}} Z_{\mathscr{kl}}).$$

We have three situations of the covariance terms

$$\operatorname{Cov}(Z_{\mathscr{ij}} Z_{\mathscr{kl}}) = \begin{cases} 
V & \quad \text{if $\mathscr{ij} = \mathscr{kl}$ or if $\mathscr{ij} = \mathscr{lk}$} \\
C & \quad \text{if ($\mathscr{i} = \mathscr{k}$ and $\mathscr{j}\neq \mathscr{l}$) or  ($\mathscr{i} = \mathscr{l}$ and $\mathscr{j} \neq \mathscr{k}$)} \\
0 & \quad \text{if $\mathscr{i} \neq \mathscr{j} \neq \mathscr{k} \neq \mathscr{l}$} \\
\end{cases}$$

For each $\mathscr{ij}$ pair, there are 2 cases of $V$ and $2 (n-2)$ cases of $C.$

Then the variance can be computed as

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(S_n) &= \left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \right)^2 \sum_{\mathscr{i}\neq \mathscr{j}} (2V+ 2(n-2)C) \\[6pt]
&= \left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \right)^2  (n(n-1)) (2V+ 2(n-2) C) \\[6pt]
&= 2 \frac{V+(n-2)C}{n(n-1)}
\end{align} $$
and this approaches zero for increasing $n$.

Comment: A side note, Sextus, try to not define the new commands at the beginning of the post - it inadvertently creates an unusual space at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @User1865345 I didn't do that ;-)

Comment: I see, Sextus. It was Michael Hardy. But the comment stands!

Comment: Now I know why some other people could use `\var` in the same way like `\sin` in their posts, while it doesn't work automatically in my posts. Those posts where I saw it must have had some commands defined somewhere in the post. I actually would prefer such definitions in the beginning, but since that reduces the layout I have removed it altogether.

Comment: It's easy to define new commands in $\LaTeX, $ (do it before starting the document environment) but here you need to resort to tricks like these. Personally I don't like the $Var$ but (as a user who edits vociferously) I won't base my edit of another user's post simply to change that to $\rm{Var}.$

Comment: There is a problem associated with defining commands here: the definitions apply to all posts (and perhaps comments -- I haven't checked) on that page, no matter whose.  Consequently, for posts on this site, I have adopted a cut-and-paste practice rather than the more elegant approach of command definition.

Comment: Do C & V always exist?

Comment: @innisfree Yes, since all $Z_{\mathscr{ij}}$ have second moments $\leq 1$.

Comment: @statmerkur ah, the fact we had sin function was important here?

Comment: @innisfree the covariance of two random variables exists if both have finite second moments and here we even have $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[Z_{\mathscr{ij}}^2\right] \leq 1$ since $Z_{\mathscr{ij}}^2 \leq 1$ (for the real-valued $\sin$) for all $\mathscr{i}, \mathscr{j}$.

Comment: Indeed, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Acting hastily, I first thought that the boundeness of $Y_{ij}\mathrel{:=\sin(X_iX_j)}$ and $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[Y_{ij}^2\right] \leq \mathbb E[1] = 1$ would be enough to solve the problem with a version of the strong law of large numbers for pairwise uncorrelated random variables.
However, clearly, in general we don't have pairwise uncorrelatedness of $Y_{ij}$ and $Y_{ik}$ for $j \neq k$ if $X_i \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathbb P$ for an arbitrary distribution $\mathbb P$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R).$

---

We can exploit the following result (e.g., Brown, 1992, Proposition 1) to  show almost sure convergence:

*Suppose that $\left(X_k\right)_{k \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}}$ is a sequence of complex-valued random variables of bounded modulus and that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right|^2\right] < \infty.
$$
Then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nX_k \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ almost surely.*

This result is a slight generalization of Theorem 1 in Lyons (1988), in which $|X_k|\leq 1$ almost surely $\forall \,k \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$ is assumed, and can be proved analogously.

---

Let $\mu \mathrel{:=} \mathbb E[Y_{ij}].$
Applying the above result to the sequence $\left(Y_{ij}-\mu\right)_{i \neq j}$ with
$$
\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)} \sum_{i \neq j}^n \left(Y_{ij}-\mu\right)\right|^2\right] 
= 
\mathop{\mathbb V}\left[\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)} \sum_{i \neq j}^n Y_{ij}\right]
$$
and $\mathop{\mathbb V}\left[\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)} \sum_{i \neq j}^n Y_{ij}\right] = 2 \frac{V+(n-2)C}{n(n-1)} \leq c/n$ (for all $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 2}$ and a constant $c \in \mathbb R_{>0}$)
from [Sextus Empiricus' answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/629411/136579) yields
$$
\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)} \sum_{i \neq j}^n \left(Y_{ij}-\mu\right)\underset{n \to \infty}{\overset{\mathrm{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}} 0,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)} \sum_{i \neq j}^n Y_{ij} \underset{n \to \infty}{\overset{\mathrm{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}} \mu.
$$

---

**References**

- Brown, G. (1992). [Some new applications of Riesz products](https://projecteuclid.org/proceedings/proceedings-of-the-centre-for-mathematics-and-its-applications/Miniconference-on-Probability-and-Analysis/Chapter/Some-new-applications-of-Riesz-products/pcma/1416322688?tab=ArticleFirstPage). *Miniconference on Probability and Analysis*, *29*, 1–13.
- Lyons, R. (1988). [Strong laws of large numbers for weakly correlated random variables](https://doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1029003816). *Michigan Mathematical Journal*, *35*(3), 353–359.

Comment: The terms are not independent. I don’t know if there’s a particular law of large numbers which works with a dependence structure of this form — perhaps a triangular array LLN?

Comment: I tried this trick relating to the Borel–Cantelli lemma, but I had a converging series instead. Are you sure it isn't $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right|^2\right] < \infty.$$ instead of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right|^2\right] < \infty.$$

Comment: Possibly it helps that the summands are bounded.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus from what I know the result should be how I've stated it, I didn't check the proof though. Without the factor $1/n$ the result wouldn't apply because the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c/n$ diverges.

Comment: @statmerkur I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma with but that would not have the factor 1/n in front of it. The case that you mention is stronger and I believe that it works because of the additional condition that the summands are bounded (but I wouldn't be able to easily write a proof)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yes, it certainly doesn't hold for general unbounded random variables. And since the OP mentioned this was a problem in an entrance exam I'm pretty sure there is an easier solution. I also tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma, but didn't find a suitable convergent series of tail probabilities.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I've added a reference that proves (a slight variation on) the result, in case you're interested.