# Almost sure convergence of $\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j$

Tags: probability, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to prove that:

> Given a sequence $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of independent and identically distributed random variables, $E(X_i^2) < +\infty$ for all $i \geq 1$, then $$\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j \xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{} E(X)^2 \;\; \text{a.s}$$

My solution so far is to write $$\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k\right)^2 - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k^2\right)$$ then using the strong law of large numbers:$$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} E(X) \;\; \text{a.s}$$so$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k\right)^2 \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} E(X)^2 \;\; \text{a.s}$$and$$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k^2 \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} E(X^2) \;\; \text{a.s}$$Then$$\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j = \frac{n^2}{n(n-1)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k\right)^2 - \frac{1}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k^2\right) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} E(X)^2 \;\; \text{a.s}$$

But I find this solution is not natural since it strictly depends on the identity $$\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k\right)^2 - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}X_k^2\right)$$then it would not work for another kind of sum.

Moreover, I found from [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629376/show-that-frac1nn-1-sum-i-neq-j-sin-leftx-i-x-j-right-converges-a) on this site that there is a more general result $$\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} h(X_i, X_j) \xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{} E\left(h(X_1, X_2)\right) \;\; \text{a.s}$$but the answer requires a theorem of $U$-statistics that is beyond my knowledge.

So my question is: *is there simpler solution for my original problem (i.e. the case of $h(X_i, X_j) = X_i X_j$)?*

Edit: this question has been posted at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4871913/1074816) but didn't capture much attention.

Comment: "Not natural" is in the eye of the beholder.  What exactly are you referring to by "another kind of sum"?  Are you suggesting you really have a different sum in mind?  If so, ask about it specifically.

Comment: Thank you. I'm agree that "...in the eye of the beholder..". But I was thinking of, for example the convergence of \sum X_iX_j - (X_1X_2 + X_2X_4 + X_3X_6 +...). In general, some special subset of (i,j) (0 < i < j < n+1).

Comment: One suitable generalization would be to diagonalize each term of the sum, hopefully in a way that is consistent from one term to the next.

Comment: @whuber thank you. Could you elaborate a little bit about "...diagonalize each term of the sum..."? I still do not understand what it means.

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiagonalQuadraticForm.html and research the spectral theorem.